# Unable to change the value of foreign key to foreign key of an object Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am having a model structure like:

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tasks = models.IntegerField(default=0)



class project(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    expected_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False,)
    actual_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False,blank=True,null=True,)
```

I want to traverse through the task list and if actual date field is not null i.e. task completed then to update the tasks field in user class by 1. I have written the following code:

```
a = task.objects.filter(actual_date__isnull=False)
for x in a:
    x.project.worker.tasks+=1
```

However this is not giving the desired result. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks a lot @solarissmoke ! Worked out perfectly! Regarding the naming convention, actually it's a demand from the administrator regarding the names they need. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving your object after modifying it - simply modifying the value doesn't write it to the database. Try this instead:

```
a = task.objects.filter(actual_date__isnull=False)
for x in a:
    worker = x.project.worker
    worker.tasks += 1
    worker.save()
```

On a separate note you should consider following PEP8 conventions and using CamelCase for your class names. As it is currently you can very easily mix up classes with objects.